# Can't remap plus minus (±) sign to tilde sign (~)

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

Until the last update to Sonoma 14.2 (23C64) I used the following script to remap the absolutely USLESS `±` sign to the FREQUENTLY used in nearly ALL of the programming languages `~`:

```
UserKeyMapping:(
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771125;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771172;
    },
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771172;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771125;
    }
)
```

Now it doesn't work and I again stuck with the misplaced `±` and `~`.

Is there any other way to change this annoying issue?

Comment: What spec keyboard do you have & what's your input language? The usual answer to this, btw is use [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) {freeware}

Comment: See if this custom layout helps:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/26af8bwn0y1j7p4/US%20ISO%20HiTilde.keylayout.zip?dl=0